# Recalculate view bounds when using relative positioning

Tags: react-native

I have a view and one of the children is using relative position, which means that I have change its top property and thus it no longer appears at the end of the view, however this messes up the whole layout because the view still leaves the space for the relative-positioned element.

Is there anyway to tell a view to recalculate its bounds when any of the children is using relative positioning?

Comment: Can you add code on rnplay?